# Modify VB code in MS Word to change image text-wrapping

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

In this code for image resizing:

```
Sub resize()
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
        With .InlineShapes(i)
            .ScaleHeight = 50
            .ScaleWidth = 50
        End With
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

I want to include a command to change the text wrapping from default (inline) to 'top and bottom'.  What code do I need to add?

Answer (score 1):

An inline shape does not have wrapping text, only regular shapes do, so you have to convert the inline shape. When doing this in an looping fashion as the macro is setup to perform, the total number of inline shapes in the document changes with each iteration and the new total recalculated. At best case, this can really slow down the process and at worst case, objects can get missed.

The fix is to work backwards from the last inline shape to the first.

```
Sub resize()
Dim i As Long, rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
    For i = .InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        With .InlineShapes(i)
            .ScaleHeight = 50
            .ScaleWidth = 50
            Set rng = .Range
            .ConvertToShape
            rng.ShapeRange(1).WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapTopBottom
        End With
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```